# cordova plugin installation to a IBM MobileFirst 7.1 project using plugman

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, plugman

When I am trying to add a cordova plugin to MobileFirst 7.1 project using plugman, cmd is giving "Access is denied" message. Can any one help me to add plugin using plugman to a MobileFirst 7.1 project.

Below is the command used to install plugin using plugman.

C:\Users\lap>plugman install --platform android --project I:\Eclipse Workspace\sampleApp\apps\sampleApp --plugin cordova-plugin-keyboard

Access is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova plugman is not supported in Hybrid apps generated by MobileFirst Studio/CLI 7.1.

To use Plugman you should upgrade to MobileFirst Foundation 8.0, which now supports standard Cordova application development.

If you cannot move to v8.0, your alternative is to create custom Cordova plug-ins: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/adding-native-functionality/